# Android Material Slider - programatically show label

Tags: android, slider, material-design

The label is normally hidden until user pressed the handle (thumb).
This all works fine.

But is there a way to show the label programmatically for a few seconds?

Basically show the label without the user touching the slider. Not show the label all the time.

For example, if I use a slider to represent volume in my app. When I use the hardware volume up and down buttons, the slider moves - but does not show the value label in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
slider.labelBehavior = LabelFormatter.LABEL_VISIBLE
```

You can manage this **labelBehavior** by programming it.

Comment: I understand that. Tell me how to temporarily show the label, say for 3 seconds, without touching the thumb.